# Twilio SMS Webhooks and Group Text Messages

Tags: ios, swift, sms, twilio, sms-gateway

Is it possible to maintain both group text messages and single text messages with users and keep them separate? I understand there is no concept of a group message per se, but wanted to see if any recent advances in tech has made this possible with Twilio or other providers.

In short, I am creating a POC where a user inside an iOS App can send invoke an API call to my backend application. This application receives a phone number from someone's contact list, and then connects to Twilio to send the SMS message to that target user.

When the user replies, I was researching Twilio Web hooks to receive the message, and then save it in the database. The originating user, then, would be able to see the message on a screen.

I would guess that when a user responds to the twilio message, the only metadata that comes in is their message and phone number, so the "foreign key" is the phone number.. Thus when I save it in my database, I have their phone number and message.

This works up until someone decides to target two or more people in an SMS message using my API, and then target one of those people individually. For example they select me as a sole recipient, and then select me and someone else as a group text message.

In this case, how could my system/Twilio differentiate between if I was responding to the group message, or to the single message?

Any ideas or work arounds? Maybe another technology? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to provide an answer to this in case anyone else was looking into this.

Essentially you pay 3 cents (0.03) per month per active user in each group. Basically you buy phone numbers for each group chat you need.

https://www.twilio.com/conversations/pricing

So if you're doing a million group chats obviously it can get costly, but for simple POCs this isn't the end of the world.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Group texts (at least those started by Android's Messages app & Google Voice) are actually Group MMS.  In my Twilio messages webhook receiver, I get extra headers `OtherRecipients0` - `OtherRecipientsN` which can be used to disambiguate one group text from another or another 1:1 SMS message.